# Send list of objects with different classes derived from same parent in a WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

```
public class Question {    
    String QuestionsID = ""; 
}
public class QuestionTrueOrFalse : Question {
    public string Answer ="";
}
public class QuestionMultipleChoice : Question {
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> obj;
}
public class MultipleChoiceOption {
    public int OptionMultipleChoiceID = 0;
    public string OptionsTextAr = "", Answer = "";
}
```

I have two classes derived from the same parent,  as shown above,  and I want to send a list of objects that contain both `QuestionMultipleChoice` and `QuestionTrueOrFalse`  from a web service. The return object is:

```
public class ReturnedObjectList<T>{   
    public List<T> ListItems = new List<T>);   
    public string Status="" ,Message="";
}
```

My webservice is:

```
public ReturnedObjectList<Question> SelectQuestions(string ID)
{ 
    ReturnedObjectList<Question> obj = new ReturnedObjectList<Question>();
    obj.ListItems.Add(new QuestionMultipleChoice());
    obj.ListItems.Add(new QuestionTrueOrFalse());
    return obj;
}
```

When I test this web service in Postman I don't get any response.

The code will work only when I add only one type of object in list, ie. if I change my returned object to contain only one type of object:

```
ReturnedObjectList<QuestionMultipleChoice> obj = new ReturnedObjectList<QuestionMultipleChoice>();
```

I want to send all type of questions in one list as json to mobile app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't defined a [Data Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) for your Custom Type (such as your `Question` type) only public properties on your class will be serialized.

It is, generally, a good idea to explicitly define [Data Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Data Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for your Custom Types.

I would suggest the following class definitions for your Custom Types:

```
[DataContract]
public class Question
{
    [DataMember]
    String QuestionsID { get; set; } = "";
}

[DataContract]
public class QuestionTrueOrFalse : Question
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Answer { get; set; } = "";
}

[DataContract]
public class QuestionMultipleChoice : Question
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> obj { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MultipleChoiceOption
{
    [DataMember]
    public int OptionMultipleChoiceID { get; set; } = 0;
    [DataMember]
    public string OptionsTextAr { get; set; } = "";
    [DataMember]
    public string Answer { get; set; } = "";
}
```

You also need to add the [KnownTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your `ReturnedObjectList` and you can return a list of `Question`.

Try the following code for the `ReturnedObjectList`:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(QuestionTrueOrFalse))]
[KnownType(typeof(QuestionMultipleChoice))]
public class ReturnedObjectList<Question>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Question> ListItems = new List<Question>();
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; } = "";
    public string Message { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay .Now i got result in postman but it is empty. but in function it returned two object

Comment: there is syntax error.and not work after fix it
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public ReturnedObjectListQ<Question> SelectQuestions(string QIDs, string StudentID, string QuizID, string Pending)
    {  ReturnedObjectListQ<Question> obj = new ReturnedObjectListQ<Question>();
        obj.ListItems.Add(new QuestionMultipleChoce());
        obj.ListItems.Add(new QuestionTrueOrFalse());
        return obj;
    } any problem in this call

Comment: when i add [datamember] to this class
public class ReturnedObjectList<Question>
{
    public List<Question> ListItems = new List<Question>();
    public string Status = "", Message = "";
}
it works .If you edit your answer i will accept it .Thanks For you replay :)

Comment: Right, I had missed `[DataMemeber]` on `ReturnedObjectList` :)